# Find distinct internet providers given a cross matrix

Tags: python, matrix, set, intersection

Assume you are only given a symmetric 2D cross matrix below where each value denote how many providers cater to those regions. For example in the 1st row, 3rd column, there are 2 providers which serve Region Y and region Z.

|  | Y | A | Z | X | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | 3 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Z | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| X | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Given only the cross matrix above, write a function to find the distinct internet providers in the network. In the example above, number of distinct internet providers is 7.

I think this problem is using the inclusion-exclusion principle. I figured that the sum of the diagonal of the cross matrix is essentially equal to the set of all providers that serve all states which will include duplicate providers. However, I am having trouble finding the intersection set so that I can remove the duplicates. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The matrix is not clear for me. Are , A,Z, X, B the same regions in the x and y axis? ANd what does mean the numbers more precisesly ? "3" means that there are 3 providers which deserves simultaneously Y and Y ? "2" means that there are 2 providers which deserves simultaneously Y and Z ? please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Malo Yes, A,Z,X,B are the same regions in the x and y axis. The numbers mean how many providers serve the two regions. For example, in row 1 column 3, two providers both simultaneously serve region Y and Z . In the case where we have identical regions eg.(Y,Y) in row 1 column 1; this means that there are 3 providers that serve region Y. Hope this clarifies the question